# Angular 2: DatePipe Error only in Safari

Tags: javascript, angular, safari

I am using the Angular2 DatePipe to format my dates I am getting from an API call, but it doesn't work only on Safari. It works as expected on every other browser. Here is the Error that I am getting.

```
Runtime Error:
InvalidPipeArgument: '2015-02-26 14:10:43' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this error?